# How to get the group of different intervals in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, eval

I have one pyspark Dataframe with different intervals and his equivalent groups. And I need to eval the column of other dataframe and get the group of the interval that follow the data

This are the intervals

````
``` # +---+-----------------+
# | start | end      | grupo|
# +---+------------------+
# |  0    |    10    |  1  | 
# |  11   |    27    |  2  | 
# |  28   |    33    |  3  | 
# |  34   |    41    |  4  | 
# |  42   |    46    |  5  | 
# +---+--------------------+```
````

And I have this:

```
 # +---+
# | result| 
# +---+----
# |  5    | 
# |  7    |
# |  33   | 
# |  22   |  
# |  41   | 
# +---+----
```

And I need this

````
``` # +---+-------
# | result| grupo|
# +---+-----------
# |  5    |    1| 
# |  7    |    1| 
# |  33   |    3|  
# |  22   |    2| 
# |  41   |    4| 
# +---+----------
````

Comment: Please indicate the code you wrote for the obtained result

Comment: It is another DF

Comment: Well, it looks like a very simple join condition: what did you try so far?

Comment: I did it with a join. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the df containing intervals and result based such that
`df["result"].between(df_intervals["start"], df_intervals["end"])`

## Working Example

```py
df_intervals = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 10, 1, ),
(11, 27, 2, ),
(28, 33, 3, ),
(34, 41, 4, ),
(42, 46, 5, ),], ("start", "end", "group", ),)

df = spark.createDataFrame([(5, ), 
(7, ),
(33, ), 
(22, ),  
(41, ), ], ("result", ))

(df_intervals.join(df, df["result"].between(df_intervals["start"], df_intervals["end"]))
             .select("result", "group")).show()

"""
+------+-----+
|result|group|
+------+-----+
|     5|    1|
|     7|    1|
|    22|    2|
|    33|    3|
|    41|    4|
+------+-----+
"""
```

Comment: I got an error because my df has more than 5 rows; ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: @alfonsomore the number of rows should not be a factor for this join. What are the datatypes of your columns?

Comment: Also I provided a PySpark solution and the error seems to be related to Pandas.